# Process data after multiple async

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have to send out multiple async GET (not simultaneously) to different URLs. Each response is stripped to get `value`. All values from all responses are put into an array `values[]` for further processing.

I can do this easily in Java or sync ajax but my question is how to do it properly with async ajax calls in JavaScript since I have little experience with this pattern. Answers using jQuery (or other relevant libarries) are acceptable too.

Thank you!

Comment: Are the requests sent one after another or are they random or sporadic?

Comment: @RandyCasburn my specific case: the requests are sent after one another. But I'm interested in your thought if they are sent out sporadically too.

Comment: I was going to suggest `Promise.all()` if sent one after another. Hadn't really thought about sporadic requests. I will...

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements you should use `promises` instead of `ajax`.
A simple example of promise-

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
if (function worked) {
resolve("Your data");
}
else {
reject(Error(oops!!));
}
});

promise.then(function(result) {
console.log(result); 
}, function(err) {
console.log(err); 
});
```